# The smallest dimension faithful representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

What can be said about $N_G$ the minimum of the dimensions of the set of trivial kernel complex linear representation of a group $G$? The regular representation (group elements are the basis of the vector space) will always have trivial kernel but it has dimension equal to the order of the group so it often wont be the minimiser of the dimension. For example cyclic groups have a dimension 1 representations with trivial kernel.

For simple groups the question simplifies to what is the minimum dimension of the nontrivial irreducible representations. It might be that the general case is deduced from this one but my group theory is a bit rusty.

Comment: You can always take the regular rep minus the trivial rep. This is still faithful. In general, you take sums of distinct irreducible reps such that their kernels have trivial intersection. It is not easy to find such a minimum in general. Addressing the title of your question: There is no way to identify a group just by this number. There are too many groups...

Comment: I realize my title should have been "the smallest representation that identifies a group" instead of the other way around.